# Add XElement to list and have it's children be remainder of list

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

If I have the following xml:

```
<Employees>
<Person>
    <ID>1000</ID>
    <Name>Nima</Name>
    <LName>Agha</LName>
</Person>
<Person>
    <ID>1002</ID>
    <Name>Ligha</Name>
    <LName>Ligha</LName>
</Person>
<Person>
    <ID>1003</ID>
    <Name>Jigha</Name>
    <LName>Jigha</LName>
</Person>
</Employees>
```

I want to add a new node, after an indexed  node, and add the remaining person nodes as the children of this new node.

So the new xml after adding would look like this:

```
<Employees>
<Person>
    <ID>1000</ID>
    <Name>Nima</Name>
    <LName>Agha</LName>
</Person>
<RefNode>
    <Person>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <Name>Ligha</Name>
        <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1003</ID>
        <Name>Jigha</Name>
        <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
</RefNode>
</Employees>
```

So far I have tried using

```
ElementAt(index).AddAfterSelf()
```

but that just adds it next in line, and doesn't add the next two Persons as children.

Comment: Do it in two steps.  First create new XElement AfterSelf.  Then move nodes into new element.

Comment: I think you missunderstood what `AddAfterSelf()` method does please refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.addafterself?view=netframework-4.8).
That method doesn't move next nodes as childs of the new added node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as following. Have added comments in code for better understanding

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// Unclear how you are identifying the node after which the change has to happen. For sake of example, using ID
var selectedNode = xdoc.Descendants("Person")
                       .First(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("ID").Value)==1000);

// Collection of nodes that would be added as child of newly inserted node
var nodeAfterSelectedNode = xdoc.Descendants("Person")
                                .SkipWhile(x=>x==selectedNode) 
                                .ToList();

// Create the new node with previously identified 'nodeAfterSelectedNode' as Children
var newElement = new XElement("RefNode",nodeAfterSelectedNode);

// Remove the existing Nodes (ones that are being moved to child) 
foreach(var node in nodeAfterSelectedNode)
{
   node.Remove();
}
// add the new node 
selectedNode.AddAfterSelf(newElement);
var newXml = xdoc.ToString();
```

Output

```
<Employees>
  <Person>
    <ID>1000</ID>
    <Name>Nima</Name>
    <LName>Agha</LName>
  </Person>
  <RefNode>
    <Person>
      <ID>1002</ID>
      <Name>Ligha</Name>
      <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <ID>1003</ID>
      <Name>Jigha</Name>
      <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
  </RefNode>
</Employees>
```

Output Sample